# Base rate effects on object detection neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose that we are training an neural network for object detection.  It is natural to train the neural network on images that contain the object in question.  However, this might have the effect of biasing the "base rate" of the network: The network "expects" there to be at least one object worth detecting in any image.

Are there any scholarly articles that investigate this phenomenon, and the effect of strategies to alleviate it (such as adding more true negatives to the training data)?